# How do you install .Net 2.0 in Windows Sandbox on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows-sandbox

We have an application written in Delphi 2007 which requires the presence of .Net 2.0 in Windows. I have tried to install this application in Windows Sandbox, but it fails since it needs those .Net 2.0 files. When I start optionalfeatures.exe in the sandbox it shows a blank window, with no optional features and thus no obvious way to install/enable .Net 2.0 in the sandbox.

Does anybody know a trick or shortcut to install .Net 2.0 in the Windows Sandbox????

Comment: Don't know if it works on windows sandbox: but could you try with powershell? Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx3"

Comment: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx3"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand

Comment: Have you tried the [offline installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=6523) ?

Comment: Yup, now I have, to no avail :-) nothing happens. As I understand it the .Net 2.0 framework is somehow incorporated in Windows 10, and should only be enabled for it to work.